# How do I reset a WOO tablet MODEL NO: PAD705?

Tags: tablet

I know you can reset an android tablet by pressing the volume button and the power button at the same time. Problem is this model doesn't have a volume button and the tablet is stuck on the android greeting screen so I can't even get into the homescreen. I don't have a pc either so I can't do it that way. I was just wondering if there is another way to reset this model without a pc?

Comment: Is there a small hole somewhere near the power button? If so, that's probably the reset button, which you can press with the end of a paperclip or similar.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. It has a headphone jack, a micro SD card slot, USB port and the power button. I'm guessing this means I have to find a pc to use? Thank you for your response anyway.